# How to handle .then and .catch in a jest unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using react with an apollo client and I'm trying to test a function, which calls for a graphQL mutation. As this is a unit test for the function, I don't want to test the mutation.
So I need to mock the mutation. This is my function:

```
changeContent (event) {
  const { content } = this.state
  const { id, language, changeMutation, t } = this.props

  changeMutation({
    variables: {
      id,
      content
    },
    refetchQueries: [{
      query: getContent,
      variables: {
        id,
        language
      }
    }]
  }).then(response => {
    this.setState({ content: response.data.changeContent.content })
  }).catch(error => {
    this.setState({ content })
    console.error(error)
    toast.error(t('error:content'))
  })
}
```

And this is how I started to test it:

```
it('changeContent() should call mutation', () => {
  // SETUP
  const initial = 'Initial value'
  const new = 'New value'
  wrapper = shallow(<Content
    id='123'
    language='en'
    t={jest.fn()}
    changeMutation={jest.fn()}
  />)
  wrapper.setState({ content: initial })
  // EXECUTE
  wrapper.instance().changeContent()
  // VERIFY
  expect(wrapper.instance().state.content).toEqual(new)
})
```

But I do not understand how to handle `then` and `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two possible expectation here:

1. when the promise from changeMutation is resolved.
2. when the promise from changeMutation is rejected.

so you could test your expected behavior making two test one for each expectation, and mock properly the changeMutation on each test maybe something like that:

**when the promise is resolved:**

```
    it('changeContent() should call mutation', async () => {
  // SETUP
  const initial = 'Initial value'
  const new = 'New value'
  wrapper = shallow(<Content
    id='123'
    language='en'
    t={jest.fn()}
    changeMutation={jest.fn(()=>Promose.resolve(yourExpectedResponse)}
  />)
  wrapper.setState({ content: initial })
  // EXECUTE
 await wrapper.instance().changeContent()
  // VERIFY
  expect(wrapper.instance().state.content).toEqual(new)
})
```

**and when the promise from changeMutation is rejected.**

```
it('changeContent() should call mutation', async () => {
  // SETUP
  const initial = 'Initial value'
  const new = 'New value'
  wrapper = shallow(<Content
    id='123'
    language='en'
    t={jest.fn()}
    changeMutation={jest.fn(()=>Promose.reject(yourExpectedError´)}
  />)
  wrapper.setState({ content: initial })
  // EXECUTE
  await wrapper.instance().changeContent()
  // VERIFY
  expect(wrapper.instance().state.content).toEqual(initial)
})
```

let me know if this is what you are asking for

Comment: Is it possible to define `resolve` and `reject` at the same time to the Promise? And then use the part in the test which is needed...

Comment: Could you show me an example for that? I think that is what I'm looking for.